# how to get docopt default args when script loaded as module

Tags: python, docopt

I'm working on a large project with multiple authors, so I'm trying to avoid making too many changes. I have one script which uses docopt to pass options, and sets some of them to default values.

I loaded a class from that script by importing it as a module, but when I called a method, it failed because it expected a default option to be set by docopt, of which there are many. Is there a way to pull in the default options from docopt?

Answer (score 0):

I realized when I was almost done writing this that there was a fairly simple solution.

```
import script
from script import SomeClass

default_args = docopt(script.__doc__, ['--required-opt', 'dummy-value'])
args = {'foo': 'bar'}
default_args.update(args)
SomeClass.some_classmethod(default_args)
```